# Pass connection information and parameters to server based SSIS job from vb.net

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, parameters, ssis, vb.net-2010

After reviewing all the different options I am still confused.
Here is the scenario.  We have multiple databases on the same server that we would like to have a Single SSIS job handle imports (or exports) into (from) a table from a file.  We are calling this from vb.net and the job is running on SSIS on the server.  We don't have xp_cmdshell available.
We need to pass to the job unique job information (it is possible that 2 people could be running the same job on the same db or on a different db on the same server), the database connection information (This cannot be stored and selected in the job, as db's may be added/removed as needed and we don't want to reconfigure the job) and the file name/path (on the server or permitted UNC path available to SSIS).
We have looked at the option of declaring the job/job steps and then directly executing the job.  We like this idea in that the Jobs would be unique and we could have the sql proc that the job calls report issues back to a common log table by the job id, which would then be available to review.
What I don't really follow is how to pass the information that this job needs.
In http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Calling-a-SSIS-Package-a35afefb I see them passing parameters using the set command, but I get confused by the explanation of the call that things are processed twice.  Also, in that example, would I be changing the Master DB reference to my DB in the Add Job Step?
My issue is that no example is really clean and simple passing parameters and changing DB's, a lot use different options like a list of db's to process from a data source and none really cleanly show me what to do with a variable that will be passed on down to a called stored procedure.
I don't have time to delve deep and experiment, I need to see how it is done as I am trying to understand it at a level back so I know how we can utilize it and fit the information we need to use (ie what do I need for connection information to dynamically assign it) as I need to know it to understand where in the grand scheme I am getting that information.  (We don't store that in the actual DB doing the job, we have a repository in a central DB for that, but I don't know exactly what I need to store!)
Brian

Comment: Why are you trying to do this through SQL Agent and/or the SQL Server?  Every problem that you are running into is because you are trying to take this "tail-wagging-the-dog" approach.  For instance, you say "*it is possible that 2 people could be running the same job on the same db or on a different db on the same server*".  But this is *not* possible with SQL Agent, under no circumstances can it run two instances of the same job at the same time, it's physically impossible for it to do that (never mind how likely it is that the SSIS package would conflict with itself).

Comment: @RBarryYoung is right, there can not be more than one instance of a single job running in SQL Agent at any time. If there is not a prohibitively large number of tables being imported and exported to, consider making a job that handles each unique case.

Comment: Ok, if I don't have to worry about multiple jobs conflicting that is fine. I plan to make a case for each table, the situation is that each DB has to be dealt with.  I do not want jobs for each DB.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters that are dynamic to a single run of a job can be passed in to the SSIS package through a config table. The process that starts the job sets any necessary parameters in the config table before starting the job. The job kicks off the SSIS package, which has a connection manager to read the values out of the config table and into parameter values within the SSIS package.

You mentioned that you have database connection information, and if you choose to pass in parameters through a table keep in mind that storing SQL login information in a database is bad practice. The connection manager in the SSIS package should use windows authentication, and permissions needed by the SSIS package can be granted to the SQLAgent service account.

Comment: I understand about storing SQL login information in the DB.  We have it secured where we need it.  My biggest concern is handling the different databases.  If we use the SQLAgent account, what do I need to do to tell the job what database it should run against?

Comment: The SSIS package would read the database name out of the config table and update the connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to run a package (or packages)via a SQLAgent job and the database it will run against is subject to change.

As supergrady says, you can pass in specific parameters to the package through a config table.

What I did was to create a config table and add a status column (a bit that indicates on/off, true/false). This allows me to run a sql script setting the status for the specific databases that I want and turning off those that I don't want. For me this is easier than opening up the job and fiddling with the command line values which is another way of getting what you want. I hope this helps

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to create a config table in my control DB that I populate with the parameters, including the database, that I want the job to look at.  Since the database and the path involved are unknown to me at design time, these would purely come from runtime data I have based on the database I am using.  If I use a Service account and windows security, I can simply change the connection info DB name?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. Been offline. This should work for you. This is similar to what I use in one of our applications. I use variables and expressions for the connections and retrieve these from the config table at runtime. You can select which database the packages will run against by the values in the status column of the config table